# If there are two identical rows or columns identical in a determinant, the value is 0. Is the converse true?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I know that
$$A=
\begin {vmatrix}
q&a&a \\
z&b&b \\
x&c&c \\
\end {vmatrix}
=0
$$
Because in determinants, if we have to two identical rows or columns of $A$ that are identical (in this case the second and the third columns are identical), then the value of $\det A = 0$.

But is the the converse true?
i.e. 
If I have a determinant like so 
$$
\begin {vmatrix}
q&a&a \\
z&b&b \\
x&c&v \\
\end {vmatrix}
=0
$$
does that imply that $c=v$ (so as to make the rows identical as the other two elements are)?

Comment: No, it does not imply this in general. Take the example with $q=z=x=0$. Then the determinant is always zero, even for $c\neq v$.

Comment: No, when $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, such that $\det A = 0$, then at least  one row and/or columns of the the matrix is a linear combination of one or more rows /(respectively, columns) of $A$.

Comment: So if $q = 2a$, $z= 2b$, and $x = c+v$, the determinant will be zero, because the first column, then, would be a linear combination of the 2nd and 3rd columns.

Comment: If any row or any one column, of a $3\times 3$ matrix, is a linear combination of one or more other rows/columns (respectively), the rows(columns) are linearly dependent.  And hence, the respective matrix has $\det = 0$.  Those rows (columns) not be identical to another row (column). Just that some row (column) $\alpha$ is equivalent to a linear combination of the other rows (columns) we can name $\beta$ and $\gamma$, e.g. $\alpha = a\beta + b\gamma$, where $a, b$ are merely scalars.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.

For instance,
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
2&0&0\\
3&1&2
\end{matrix}\right|=0
$$
In general, a zero determinant is equivalent to the columns (or rows) being *linearly dependent*. Two of them being equal is a special case of linear dependence.

Comment: Your example merely reinforces the OP

Comment: @jordan_glen Are you saying that $1=2$? Because that's what $c=v$ in the OP's conjecture would mean in my example.

Comment: But your matrix has two identical rows.

Comment: Your example merely reinforces the OP's question; The matrix you show has two identical rows, and it's determinant is $0$.  The asker is wanting to know whether a matrix with determinant zeros implies that the matrix has two identical rows, or two identical columns.  Your example affirms their suspicion "Yes".  If you want to argue "No it doesn't", then provide a counterexample where the matrix has determinant zero, but the matrix does not have either any identical rows, nor any identical columns.  e.g. $\begin{matrix} 1 & 2&3 \\ 2&3&5\\ 3&4&7\end{matrix}$.  No identical rows or columns...

Comment: But it's determinant is $0$, and we can understand this due to the fact that column three is merely the some of columns two and one.

Comment: @jordan_glen It was specifically about the columns, seeing as he used $c=v$. But still, I fixed it. Now no columns or rows are equal.

Comment: "Because in determinants, if we have to two identical rows or columns of A that are identical, then the value of $\det A=0$. But is the the converse true?"  The converse of the quoted sentences is "if the value of $\det A = 0$, does A necessarily have two identical rows (or two identical columns).  My answer is no, and I presented a counterexample in which $\det A = 0$ but no column nor row is identical with another, respectively.  You provided an example that only shows a matrix with determinant $0$, that has two identical rows.  Hence it is not an example of the converse of which asker asks.

Comment: Oops, I missed your update while I was writing a response.  Now you're spot on.

Comment: @jordan_glen Also, I think you missed that in the OP's conjecture, there are two $a$'s and two $b$'s. That constrained what kind of examples I _could_ use.

Comment: I took the asker to iuse last matrix as an example only, $\det = 0$, and if the converse is true, it must have least two identical columns/rows, from which they conclude $c=v$.  Any matrix with no two columns, and no two rows, identical serves as a fine example.  If you missed that with $\det =0$, "we must have that column 2 = column 3, in their example,  I think you missed the obvious intention of the asker to provide an example in which $\det M = 0 \implies c=v$, meaning col 2 = col 3, which they conjecture, if assuming the converse is true: $\det M=0\implies$ two columns/rows are identical.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin {vmatrix}
q&a&a \\
z&b&b \\
x&c&v \\
\end {vmatrix}
\xrightarrow{C_3\to C_3-C_2}
\begin {vmatrix}
q&a&0 \\
z&b&0\\
x&c&v-c\\
\end {vmatrix}
=(v-c)(qb-az)=0\implies v=c\vee qb=az$$which means the converse is not true in general.